# How to parse a Mash from LinkedIn to create a Ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, linkedin-api, parameters

I used LinkedIn gem by pengwynn to get authentication from LinkedIn. Everything works fine, and I get a Mash in a callback that looks like this:

```
#<LinkedIn::Mash all=[#<LinkedIn::Mash company=#<LinkedIn::Mash id=1422 industry="Banking"    
 name="Company" size="10,001+ employees" ticker="ABC" type="Public Company"> id=2851554 
 is_current=true start_date=#<LinkedIn::Mash month=12 year=2008> summary="" title="Boss">] total=1>
```

How can I parse it to something similar to Rails params in order to create a new object from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you receive list of connections of any sort from LinkedIn, you need to get to the list from `all`.  On the object you received from LinkedIn, you have `{all, total}`.  `total` will give you the number of objects in the array, `all` will give you all of the objects.  So if you wanted to turn the first company into a hash, you would call `object.all.first.to_hash`.  You can iterate through all of them by doing `object.all.each {|c| # your block}`.

If your own Rails models match the objects being returned from the linkedin gem, you can do:

```
companies.all.each do |company|
  Company.create(company.to_hash)
end
```

If they don't map 1:1, you can just choose the fields you want:

```
companies.all.each do |company|
  c = Company.new
  c.name = company.name
  c.year_founded = company.start_date.year
  c.ticker = company.ticker
  # etc. etc. etc.
  c.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sean and Alex. This is exactly what I need. If it is not too much to ask, could you help me with a simple example extracting all objects from all?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include an example.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks a million, Sean. The example really helps.

Comment: Hi Sean. I have a quick follow-up question: How do I convert a nested Mash to a nested Hash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can do this by calling to_hash on the parent object.  You're going to have to iterate through the fields just like above and do `value.to_hash if value.is_a(Mash)`.

Comment: Thank you for your generous help. It saves me lots of hours hacking around with Mash.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call `.to_hash` to turn a Mash into a Hash (like `params`).

Source:

https://github.com/intridea/hashie/blob/master/lib/hashie/hash.rb